# CSS doesn’t work in django site-admin on server

Tags: css, django, python-3.x

**CSS** doesn’t work on *pythonanywhere* server, but works properly on *localhost*
**Admin** **CSS** files are empty on *pythonanywhere* server

I tried changing `DEBUG = True/False`

I also tried changing *settings.py*

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static') # пустая папка, сюда будет собирать статику collectstatic
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

But that doesn’t help.

Comment: https://s3.amazonaws.com/img.takeoff/raw_photos_for_taxa/Screen+Shot+2019-06-05+at+7.52.04+PM.png
https://s3.amazonaws.com/img.takeoff/raw_photos_for_taxa/Screen+Shot+2019-06-05+at+7.52.11+PM.png
screenshots of control panel

Comment: why do you defined `STATIC_ROOT` twice? You need to run `manage.py collectstatic`, did you do that?

Comment: I have an extensive blog post on how to deploy properly to production, it's for AWS, but many of it holds true for other environments as well. You can find it [here](https://www.dedi.co/blog/entries/2018/12/17/deploying-static-files-aws-django-part-1)

Comment: @dirkgroten I tried these 2 cases, yes i used ```manage.py collectstatic``` 
And I found my mistake it was in settings on my server, 
for static automatically was wrote wrong way in one app and it was a reason why CSS for site work properly but for admin doesn’t.

Comment: Looks like you may need to set up a static files mapping on web tab on the PythonAnywhere dashboard.
see: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles/

Answer (score 0):

Your static files for admin pages are kept in:

```
\YourDjangoProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static
```

I solved the problem by adding this path to Static Files section in PythonAnywhere Web tab.
Map URL to `/static/admin,` and Directory to 
`/home/username/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/`
That should fetch css files for admin pages.